# Return a copy of a row in a table

Tags: python

If I have a table (CSV) of data and the first column of data is an ID. I want to write code to search for the ID in the first column and then return a copy of the entire row of data for that corresponding ID. Sorry if it is a simple question, I am newer to python and struggling with this. I thought maybe you would search column one for the row number of the ID and then from there return the whole row. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Table Example:

```
ID,LAST NAME,FIRST NAME,DOB
A001,Smith,Bob,1995-07-23
A002,Jones,John,1962-05-15
A003,Walker,Willy,1984-01-12
A004,Kelly,Sara,2001-12-01
```

```py
def get_id_row(id,table):
    """id: id you want to search
       table: is a 2 dim table"""
    pass
```

Comment: What form does this table take? A list of lists? A dataframe? Please give an explicit example.

Comment: It would be a table of lists so your headers would be for example: ID,LAST NAME,FIRST NAME,DOB then row 1 woulld be: 001, Smith, Bob, 1995-07-23

Comment: It would be best if you include an example of your table as code (not just a description) in the question.

Comment: I added an example of the table above.

Comment: I placed an answer before you add example table. However, you could modify it based on your requiremwnts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a psuedo code which might help you. I wrote it on my mobile phone so it might be a bit dirty.

```
IDs = [1,2,3]
values = [101,102,103]
myTable = [IDs, values]

def get_id_row(id,table):
    rowInd = 0
    for tempId in table[0]:
        if tempId == id:
            return rowInd
        rowInd += 1
        
print("Id:1 from the row number : "),
print(get_id_row(1, myTable))
print("Id:2 from the row number : "),
print(get_id_row(2, myTable))
print("Id:3 from the row number : "),
print(get_id_row(3, myTable))
```

**The output:**

> Id:1 from the row number :  0  Id:2 from the row number :  1  Id:3
> from the row number :  2

Comment: Thanks for the code. I will use it and see if I can make it work for my specific requirements. I think this is a very good start.